# How to split expression containing brackets correctly

Tags: regex

I am trying to write an expression handler that will correctly split brackets, until today it has worked very well, but I've now encountered a problem I hadn't thought of.

I try to split the expression by the content of brackets first, once these are evaluated I replace the original content with the results and process until there are no brackets remaining.

The expression may contain marcos/variables.  Macros are denoted by text wrapped in $macro$.

A typical expression:

```
    ($exampleA$ * 3) + ($exampleB$ / 2)
```

Macros are replaced before the expression is evaluated, the above works fine because the process is as follows:

1. Split expression by brackets, this results in two expressions:

   ```
   $exampleA$ * 3
   $exampleB$ / 2
   ```
2. Each expression is then evaluated, if exampleA = 3 and exampleB = 6:

   ```
   $exampleA$ * 3 = 3 * 3 = 9
   $exampleB$ / 2 = 6 / 2 = 3
   ```
3. The expression is then rebuilt using the results:

   ```
   9 + 3
   ```
4. The final expression without any brackets is then evaluated to:

   ```
   12
   ```

This works fine until an expressions with nested brackets is used:

```
    ((($exampleA$ * 3) + ($exampleB$ / 2) * 2) - 1)
```

This breaks completely because the regular expression I'm using:

```
    regex("(?<=\\()[^)]*(?=\\))");
```

Results in:

```
    ($exampleA$ * 3
    $exampleB$ / 2
```

So how can I correctly decode this, I want the above to be broken down to:

```
    $exampleA$ * 3
    $exampleB$ / 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do. If you want to match the innermost expressions, wouldn't this help?:

```
regex("(?<=\\()[^()]*(?=\\))");
```

By the way, are the parentheses in your example unbalanced on purpose?

Comment: Thank you well spotted, that was a typo.

Comment: And does my answer help? All I did was disallow opening parenthesis inside the subexpression.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional regex cannot handle recursive structures like nested brackets.

Depending on which regex flavor you are using, you may be able to use [regex recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html).  Otherwise, you will probably need a new method for parsing the groups.  I think the traditional way is to represent the expression as a stack: start with an empty stack, push when you find a '(', pop when you find a ')'.

Comment: The issue is the expressions are used in XML attributes.  I load the attribute pass it then keep the results.  I guess one simple solution, I could pass the sub-expression and if I don't find a matching closing bracket, automatically append one or more to match ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this with regex. You really need a recursive method, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {         

        Console.WriteLine(EvaluateExpression("(1 + 2) * 7"));           

    }


    public static int EvaluateExpression(string expression) {

        // Recursively evaluate parentheses as sub expressions
        var expr = expression.ToLower();
        while (expr.Contains("(")) {

            // Find first opening bracket
            var count = 1;
            var pStart = expr.IndexOf("(", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            var pos = pStart + 1;

            // Find matching closing bracket
            while (pos < expr.Length && count > 0) {
                if (expr.Substring(pos, 1) == "(") count++;
                if (expr.Substring(pos, 1) == ")") count--;
                pos++;
            }

            // Error if no matching closing bracket
            if (count > 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("Closing parentheses not found.");

            // Divide expression into sub expression
            var pre = expr.Substring(0, pStart);
            var subexpr = expr.Substring(pStart + 1, pos - pStart - 2);
            var post = expr.Substring(pos, expr.Length - pos);

            // Recursively evaluate the sub expression
            expr = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", pre, EvaluateExpression(subexpr), post);

        }

        // Replace this line with you're own logic to evaluate 'expr', a sub expression with any brackets removed.
        return (int)new DataTable().Compute(expr, null);

    }

}
```

I'm assuming your using C# here... but you should get the idea and be able to translate it into whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following regex, you can capture them as `group(1)`. `group(0)` will have parenthesis included.

`"\\(((?:\"\\(|\\)\"|[^()])+)\\)"`

Hope it helps!